# Google Search API

Tags: google, google-search, api, google-search-api

Can someome tell me if there is an API to get search results form Google? I went through the [Google Search APIs](http://code.google.com/more/#google-search), but could not find anything that will let me get search results (the custom search api is limited to searching few sites only I think).

I have heard some tools on the web use a generic search api. Is there any such API?

Comment: If you're willing to pay for it you can get XML results from Google Site Search.

Answer (score 1):

I would think [Google's search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) is about as generic as you can get. You can also use [Bing's Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx). Or if you want something more exotic and possibly better, check out [Duck Duck Go's search API](http://duckduckgo.com/api.html).  Duck Duck Go I believe uses Google's API as well as a number of other one's so using that API and doing some research into what it does may be the most help.