# Alternative to the deprecated Google Web Seach API

Tags: search-engines, looking-for-a-script, google-search, api, alternative

This question is slightly related to the question [located here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/google-search-api).

My current solution is using the deprecated [Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) - but since it's deprecated, qeuries to the API is now limited. This is a problem for me - the suggested alternative is using the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/) but this only allows me to search on specific sites and pages. This is not what I need.

I need to be able to search the web for a query, preferebly through Google. But I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I'm able to answer my own question while using the new Custom Search API.

Creating a [Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) will initially ask you to provide sites or pages that you want your CSE to search in. By filling in a sample website and creating the CSE you are then able to manage and adjust it after the creation process. Here you can tell the CSE that you wan't it to search the entire web and not only the provided sites.

For the best search performance I selected this option and removed the site I provided initially, since the CSE will favor the sites provided in the search.

The new API is limited in the free edition to 100 queries a day. But it solves the issue I had.

Comment: How do you remove the site later?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said in your answer - "For the best search performance I selected this option and removed the site I provided initially, since the CSE will favor the sites provided in the search.". But when I removed the site; the CSE or call through API do not work. I get no results.

Comment: @RubyDev I just went to the control panel and under 'Sites' I just removed the site.

Comment: did it work after you remove site, I mean the CSE or API.

Comment: @RubyDev The API workshop fine.